# PHP constantly running for Telegram userbot

Tags: php, telegram

I use MadelineProto (PHP) for running a userbot with games.
IF I run the script and someone sents a message I return an answer. It works pretty good and fast but its now running constantly with:

```
while(true){
    //code here
}
```

But this doesnt feel like a good method.
Whats the best way to constantly run this script?

(I dont want to use a regular bot for this for several reasons and limitations)

Comment: Well, your question isn't clear enough to figure out what is going on! `while(true) {..}` is used in CLI to run a deamon or long pulling, and it cannot be used in web since It'll never end.

Comment: Well, I have a script like this example:
https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/docs/UPDATES.html#long-polling

Comment: Its not clear if you are writing a server or a client. Implementing a daemon is *very* complex (too broad) and the specifics are dependent on the operating system the program will running on (you didn't tell us - hence "unclear what you are asking). Long polling implies a client - but its now 2018 - go read up on websockets.

Comment: As I meantioned earlier and as the script stated, this is a (Long polling) which means you have to run it from CLI not from your website, either you make it a Linux service, or you just run it in cron (which is the easiest way).